# Swift 2.0, validation on DatePicker maximum Date

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker, nsdatecomponents

Suppose today's date is 16 May 2016, I want to restrict the user to display date up-to 16 jun 2016.

Comment: use maximumDate property of picker view.

Comment: Set your datepicker's `maximumDate`

Comment: A wish: today is indeed 16 May 2016, so nobody uses Swift 2.0 anymore. the current up-to-date release is 2.2.1, so please, just write Swift 2 :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Edit

**Swift 3**

```
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
```

**swift 2**

```
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
```

---

**Restrict user to particular time interval**

Try This:
It will restrict user to select date greater than one month from current date.

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
let secondsInMonth: NSTimeInterval = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate(timeInterval: secondsInMonth, sinceDate: NSDate())
```

Answer (score 4):

In swift 2.0, use the property maximumDate to solve your problem.

You can use the code like this..

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
```

Answer (score 2):

set the `maximumDate` property of `UIDatePicker`.

Answer (score 2):

The logic is like this suppose today is 16th May 2016 and you want to add 30 days then below logic would be helpful to you

```
 // Initialize stringified date presentation
var myStringDate: String = "2016-05-16"
    // How much day to add
var addDaysCount: Int = 30
    // Creating and configuring date formatter instance
var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    // Retrieve NSDate instance from stringified date presentation
var dateFromString: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myStringDate)
    // Create and initialize date component instance
var dateComponents: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
dateComponents.day = addDaysCount
    // Retrieve date with increased days count
var newDate: NSDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: dateFromString, options: 0)
NSLog("Original date: %@", dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateFromString))
NSLog("New date: %@", dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate))
// Clean up
dateComponents, dateComponents = nil
dateFormatter, dateFormatter = nil
```

New date what you get can be set to the UIDatePicker.

Answer (score 2):

You can set both Max date and Min date programmatically.

Use following code for iOS 8+

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setMonth:1];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

/* Optional for your case */
[comps setYear:-30];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate]
```

Comment: This is definitely not Swift 2.0